# convert xml file to wbxml with c program

Tags: c, xml, xml-parsing, wbxml

I have to write a C program to convert XML file to WBXML format, without using external conversion library. Is it possible?

I have created the XML file in C and now want to convert it into WBXML file.

Comment: Why is the use of external libraries prohibited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to know if it is possible? - Yes.

You want to know how? - check the implementation of one of the [external libraries](https://libwbxml.opensync.org/browser). I'm sure you can get an idea if you browse the source code.

Comment: if we direct created WBXML file which contain phone contact, how can we send to server and how server decode it.we have to send code page(user define tag used in creating wbxml) to server?

Comment: Check the libwbxml code. There are intuitive functions like xml2wbxml and wbxml2xml. You have to send any additional decoding information to the server also.